# How to return with errors in a method?

Tags: java, error-handling

Suppose there is a method:

```
MyClass myMethod(MyClass input){
    //body of method
}
```

Assume that I don't know where exactly this method may be used. If the input is null then how do I decide if I should throw an exception or just return a null value?

I have the same question for a method like

```
void myMethod(MyClass input){
    //body of method
}
```

If the input is null, should I just return without executing anything or throw an exception or say a System.error()?

I have used all these for my projects. It all works fine since most of my classes have very few public methods.

Comment: This is largely an opinion-based question, and therefore likely to be closed. However, check out Clean Code by Martin for an amazing treatise (in Java) on how to handle these situations.

Answer (score 1):

Is a null input an **EXCEPTIONAL** situation, or reasonably normal behavior? If it's exceptional behavior, throw an exception. If it's expected to happen, consider returning `null`.

Answer (score 1):

> If the input is null then how do I decide if I should throw an exception or just return a null value?

ask yourself, is `null` a valid input? if yes, don't throw exception and handle logically. if no, throw exception.

What does valid mean here is: Lets say you are storing some values in a object and some of them are optional. i.e. user may or may not provide there values. in that case `null` become valid only for those fields but for mandatory fields `null` is not acceptable.

Apply similar thinking to your problem and you may come to a conclusion.

Another example: Lets say you are opening a file where input to that method is `filePath`. if the path given is null, it's not valid and exception should be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

If input being null will create an error in your code during execution, then you should throw an exception (such as IllegalArgumentException). Otherwise you can return null.

Answer (score 0):

In general, never allow null anywhere. It only makes life difficult. Java makes it hard to follow this advice, but you do what you can with what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

If the method is not expected to be called with a null argument, it is fine to throw a NullPointerException (NPE for short), since it is a precondition that input!=null, and the caller should have verified it beforehand.

```
/** My method.
  * @param input the input, must not be null.
  */
void myMethod(MyClass input){
  if (input==null) throw new NullPointerException();
  //...
}
```

A common idiom for throwing NPE, without incrementing your program branch count is:

```
void myMethod(MyClass input){
  input.getClass(); //NPE if input is null
  //...
}
```

In some cases, the above check is implicit in the code:

```
void printLowercase(String input){
  System.out.println(input.toLowerCase());
}
```

Avoid implementing a method that fails silently, because it makes hard to the caller to know whether the method failed. Instead, return boolean.

```
boolean myMethod(MyClass input){       
   if (input==null) {
       //you may log that the input was null
       return false;
   }
   //...
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

**Tell, don't ask**

The idea is to delegate error handling to an object that can decide whether to return some value or throw an exception.

If you have control over the method signature than you can just do

```
MyClass myMethod(MyClass input, Expectation whenInputIsNull){
    if(input==null) {
        // might also throw
        return whenInputIsNull.handle();
    }
    //body of method
}
```

If you don't have control over the method signature, than you might place the `Expectation` as a member in the owning class of `myMethod`.

That can be very nice to read:

```
foo.myMethod(input, Expect.nullReturned());
foo.myMethod(input, Expect.throwIllegalArgumentException());
```

I find it very handy when this is used with repositories:

```
fooRepository.findByBar(bar, Expect.atLeast(5));
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a debatable question. I'd say consider the problem domain and choose what's best to use.

**In any case, clearly document the behaviour of your code for such inputs (using succinct Javadoc), so that users of your API are not surprised by unexpected behavior.**